# is the amortized cost of growing a numpy array O(1)?

Tags: python, numpy, dynamic-arrays

The documentation for numpy.ndarray.resize() doesn't offer any guarantees on allocation cost when growing an array.

Is it amortized-O(1), as is usual with dynamic arrays (e.g. c++'s , Java's Vector, etc)? It almost seems pedantic to ask, but I wanted to see if anybody knows for sure.

Comment: numpy arrays are not implemented as linked lists, but stored in contiguous memory blocks. Ideally, they do not grow in size. Expanding usually needs copying, which is expensive.

Comment: It can only be O(1) if the array allocates more memory than it needs, which it probably does not...  I don't know for sure though.

Comment: That's why he said "amortized". Regarding that, it almost certainly is, unless it's really badly designed.

Comment: Numpy arrays do not overallocate; the exact answer to the question then depends on what the C realloc function does, but in practice you'll probably need to deal with overallocation yourself.

Comment: If you need to build an array incrementally, it is better to build a list incrementally, and convert that to an array at the end.  Or, initial a large array, and assign values incrementally.

Comment: @hpaulj Is there an equivalent to c++'s vector::reserve() and vector::capacity() for numpy arrays? As in, can I manually overallocate without changing the stated size of the array? I couldn't find any such member methods in numpy.ndarray, but I'm wondering if there's a non-bound function in numpy.* that I haven't found.